# Dart and Antlr4 on Web - Mismatched Input

Tags: flutter, dart, antlr, antlr4

Wow, this was a terribly worded query, let me try again.

I'm still learning antlr and trying to understand grammars. I'm using a grammar (not written by me - so I'm trying not to adjust it too much as it's the standard used by many groups, [found here](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1/grammar.html)).

I'm using it in a Flutter application. When I run it on Linux or Android, it runs without issue. When I try and run it no web, I immediately have issues. The full grammar I'm using is below.

```
grammar FhirPath;

// Grammar rules [FHIRPath](http://hl7.org/fhirpath/N1) Normative Release

//prog: line (line)*; line: ID ( '(' expr ')') ':' expr '\r'? '\n';
entireExpression: expression EOF;

expression:
    term                                                # termExpression
    | expression '.' invocation                         # invocationExpression
    | expression '[' expression ']'                     # indexerExpression
    | ('+' | '-') expression                            # polarityExpression
    | expression ('*' | '/' | 'div' | 'mod') expression # multiplicativeExpression
    | expression ('+' | '-' | '&') expression           # additiveExpression
    | expression '|' expression                         # unionExpression
    | expression ('<=' | '<' | '>' | '>=') expression   # inequalityExpression
    | expression ('is' | 'as') typeSpecifier            # typeExpression
    | expression ('=' | '~' | '!=' | '!~') expression   # equalityExpression
    | expression ('in' | 'contains') expression         # membershipExpression
    | expression 'and' expression                       # andExpression
    | expression ('or' | 'xor') expression              # orExpression
    | expression 'implies' expression                   # impliesExpression;
//| (IDENTIFIER)? '=>' expression                             #lambdaExpression

term:
    invocation              # invocationTerm
    | literal               # literalTerm
    | externalConstant      # externalConstantTerm
    | '(' expression ')'    # parenthesizedTerm;

literal:
    '{' '}'                 # nullLiteral
    | ('true' | 'false')    # booleanLiteral
    | STRING                # stringLiteral
    | NUMBER                # numberLiteral
    | DATE                  # dateLiteral
    | DATETIME              # dateTimeLiteral
    | TIME                  # timeLiteral
    | quantity              # quantityLiteral;

externalConstant: '%' ( identifier | STRING);

invocation: // Terms that can be used after the function/member invocation '.'
    identifier  # memberInvocation
    | function  # functionInvocation
    | '$this'   # thisInvocation
    | '$index'  # indexInvocation
    | '$total'  # totalInvocation;

function: identifier '(' paramList? ')';

paramList: expression (',' expression)*;

quantity: NUMBER unit?;

unit:
    pluralDateTimePrecision
    | dateTimePrecision
    | STRING; // UCUM syntax for units of measure

pluralDateTimePrecision:
    'years'
    | 'months'
    | 'weeks'
    | 'days'
    | 'hours'
    | 'minutes'
    | 'seconds'
    | 'milliseconds';

dateTimePrecision:
    'year'
    | 'month'
    | 'week'
    | 'day'
    | 'hour'
    | 'minute'
    | 'second'
    | 'millisecond';

typeSpecifier: qualifiedIdentifier;

qualifiedIdentifier: identifier ('.' identifier)*;

identifier:
    IDENTIFIER
    | DELIMITEDIDENTIFIER
    | 'as'
    | 'is'
    | 'contains'
    | 'in'
    | 'div';

/****************************************************************
 Lexical rules ***************************************************************
 */

/*
 NOTE: The goal of these rules in the grammar is to provide a date token to the parser. As such it
 is not attempting to validate that the date is a correct date, that task is for the parser or
 interpreter.
 */

DATE: '@' DATEFORMAT;

DATETIME:
    '@' DATEFORMAT 'T' (TIMEFORMAT TIMEZONEOFFSETFORMAT?)?;

TIME: '@' 'T' TIMEFORMAT;

fragment DATEFORMAT:
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ('-' [0-9][0-9] ('-' [0-9][0-9])?)?;

fragment TIMEFORMAT:
    [0-9][0-9] (':' [0-9][0-9] (':' [0-9][0-9] ('.' [0-9]+)?)?)?;

fragment TIMEZONEOFFSETFORMAT: (
        'Z'
        | ('+' | '-') [0-9][0-9]':' [0-9][0-9]
    );

IDENTIFIER: ([A-Za-z] | '_') ([A-Za-z0-9] | '_')*;
// Added _ to support CQL (FHIR could constrain it out)

DELIMITEDIDENTIFIER: '`' (ESC | ~[\\`])* '`';

STRING: '\'' (ESC | ~['])* '\'';

// Also allows leading zeroes now (just like CQL and XSD)
NUMBER: [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;

// Pipe whitespace to the HIDDEN channel to support retrieving source text through the parser.
WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);

LINE_COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN);

fragment ESC:
    '\\' ([`'\\/fnrt] | UNICODE); // allow \`, \', \\, \/, \f, etc. and \uXXX

fragment UNICODE: 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX;

fragment HEX: [0-9a-fA-F];
```

I generate the code with the following:

```bash
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Dart FhirPath.g4 -visitor -no-listener
```

Then to test I use the following code:

```dart
final input = InputStream.fromString('name');
final lexer = FhirPathLexer(input);
final tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer);
final parser = FhirPathParser(tokens);
parser.buildParseTree = true;
final tree = parser.expression();
```

If I run it in a simple dart script, it runs without issue. But if I put it in a Flutter application (again, only on web, otherwise it appears to run without issue), I get this error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'name' expecting {'as', 'in', 'is', 'contains', 'div', 'mod', IDENTIFIER, DELIMITEDIDENTIFIER}
```

I assume there's something I don't understand about the grammar, so any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: There are still quite a few token recognition errors unrelated to this error, so I can't reproduce your outputr.  Please try to test that your posted grammar works and produces the output you give in your question.  It's way to easy to strip too much out, and it does make answering questions more difficult)

Comment: What I don't understand is what has this to do with Flutter?

Comment: This has to do with Flutter because I can run it in a Flutter application in Android or Linux, but not in web. Also, this same Grammar is used in Javascript and Python and works, so I'm trying to figure out where the discrepancy is.

Comment: This sounds like the generated parser is different when used in a Dart script compared to the generated parser being used in your web app. Be sure you're using the same generated parser.

Comment: I deleted my answer... I misread your question and mistook your code for testing it as the entire input.  I've rerun with the grammar you supplied and the `name` input, and get good output.  "name" is tokenized as an `IDENTIFIER`.  (This is using the Java target to test out the grammar.)

Comment: Since your message indicates that `name` is not recognized as an `IDENTIFIER`, you probably do need to double check that the grammars match and you're actually using that grammar.  I'm afraid I don't really know Dart well enough to test the Dart target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded this is an error with transpiling to javascript. The antlr4 version works for all of my tests for Android and Linux, then throws a bunch of errors for web. I've gone back to using [petitparser](https://pub.dev/packages/petitparser) instead of [antlr4](https://pub.dev/packages/antlr4). If anyone else has suggestions feel free to leave them, but for now, I'm going to close this. If you want to compare how the two look, I have both versions here: https://github.com/MayJuun/fhir/tree/main/fhir_path/lib